# Listview search not returning correct corresponding activity (TextWatcher)

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, textwatcher

I have a listview with corresponding activities that start when I click on each item. It works fine. But when I search for "Pedro" and click on it, do not start the correct activity. It opens the first activity "Joao.class"

This is my code. Please, I need a detailed explanation. I don't know Java well, so someone could explain to me or show me where I should change the code?

Thanks a lot!!!

```
public class Main extends Activity {

   private ListView lv1;
private EditText ed;
private String lv_arr[]=  {"Android","Cupcake","Donut","Eclairs","AndroidPeople","Froyo",};
private ArrayList<String> arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
long arg3) {



       if ("João".equals(lv_arr[position])) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Joao.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);
       }

       if ("Maria".equals(lv_arr[position])) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Maria.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);
       }

       if ("Pedro".equals(lv_arr[position])) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Pedro.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);
       }


}

        });





// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,    lv_arr));
ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
int count) {

textlength=ed.getText().length();
arr_sort.clear();
for(int i=0;i<lv_arr.length;i++)
{
if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length())
{
if(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0,    textlength)))
{
arr_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
}
}
}

lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1  , arr_sort));

}
});
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the data in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 does not match the data in your array AFTER it is sorted.  Instead of looking in the array, you will want to grab the value from arr_sort.  ie:

`if ("Pedro".equals(arr_sort.get(position))) {`

Comment: So, Peter, it works when I search for Pedro by now. But, the listview lv_arr doesn't work anymore. The app is playing up and it's closed when I click on a specific item :/

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more specific information for me to give you any useful information.  Ie: What is your updated onItemClick function.  What is the logcat output (from eclipse debugger) that is output when your application crashes.  (You can also download a program from the playstore called catlog to see these logs on the phone)